# Rails: Search for the same string in two tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Good evening guys, I'm new to rails and I'm using google translate to post here in English.
a doubt.

I have the users table, and in it 2 columns

```
my_code_invite_win
```

```
indication_code
```

I would like to list all users of column "indication_code" who have the same code as "my_code_invite_win", how could I do this listing?

[image: image_columns]

Comment: Roberto, two points. 1. Please do not include pictures of code or data in SO questions. That's because the link may be broken in future and because readers may wish to cut-and-paste your data or code and use it in their answers. 2) When you give an example please always show the desired result (even if you think it is obvious).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Users.where("my_code_invite_win = indication_code")`